# Calculating Month Start/End With A Fixed Last Day Of Month

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

I need to loop through each day within a month but with a fixed number as the last day of the month.

E.g. If the last day of the month is fixed as 30, 
January would become:

Start of Month: Dec 31 2012 12:00AM
End of Month:   Jan 30 2013 12:00AM

I have implemented the following which works perfectly except for the month of February. I can't seem to find a solution that will ensure this always works for every month no matter what the month end date is. 
Any suggestions are much appreciated.

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME
DECLARE @DayInstance DATETIME
DECLARE @LastDayOfMonth DATETIME
DECLARE @monthEndDate INT = 30


SET @dt = '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000'


WHILE @dt < GETDATE()
BEGIN   
    SET @DayInstance = @dt
    SET @LastDayOfMonth = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@dt))),DATEADD(mm,1,@dt)),101))

    IF @monthEndDate > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @LastDayOfMonth = DATEADD(DAY,(@monthEndDate-DATEPART(dd,@LastDayOfMonth)),@LastDayOfMonth)
            SET @DayInstance = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @LastDayOfMonth)
            SET @DayInstance = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @DayInstance)
        END
    PRINT 'Month Start Date: ' + CAST(@DayInstance AS NVARCHAR(20))
    PRINT 'Month End Date: ' + CAST(@LastDayOfMonth AS NVARCHAR(20))        
    PRINT ''    

    WHILE @DayInstance <= @LastDayOfMonth
    BEGIN
        -- Going to do more stuff here
        SET @DayInstance = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @DayInstance)
    END 

    SET @dt = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @dt)    
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this query (it can be simplified still further, but I want to show how I was thinking) sets `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` to suitable dates - you can then do your iteration between these two values:

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME
DECLARE @DayInstance DATETIME
DECLARE @monthEndDate INT = 30

SET @dt = '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000'

DECLARE @MagicDate1 DATETIME
DECLARE @MagicDate2 DATETIME

SELECT @MagicDate1 = DATEADD(day,@monthEndDate-1,'20010101'),
       @MagicDate2 = DATEADD(day,@monthEndDate-1,'20001201')

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

SELECT @StartDate = DATEADD(day,1,DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',@dt),
                           @MagicDate2)),
        @EndDate = DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',@dt),@MagicDate1)

select @StartDate,@EndDate
```

I first construct two "magic" dates. Those are, respectively the Nth day of January 2001 and the Nth day of December 2000, where N is the desired month end date. Notice that the choice of 2000/2001 was arbitrary, and never need to be changed.<sup>1</sup>

What we then do in the final expressions is to work out how many months have elapsed between January 2001 and your `@dt` variable. If we then add that same number of months onto our two "magic" dates then we end up with the Nth day of the same month as `@dt` and the Nth day of the previous month to `@dt` (Or the last day of either month if the month has fewer than N days).

Finally, we adjust what we've found as the Nth day of last month by adding 1 to it - which should be the "first" day of the current month.

---

<sup>1</sup> The only important thing is to pick two months which both have 31 days and are consecutive in the calendar. The year is arbitrary.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this. Like the way you've done it, certainly not a route I would have thought of taking. Seems to work perfectly. :-) Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've slightly over-complicated things I think the following I believe does what you want it to do:

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME
DECLARE @LastDayOfMonth DATETIME


SET @dt = '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000'
WHILE @dt < GETDATE()
BEGIN   
    SET @LastDayOfMonth = DATEADD(DAY,-1,(DATEADD(MONTH,1,@dt)))
    PRINT 'Month Start Date: ' + CAST(@dt AS NVARCHAR(20))
    PRINT 'Month End Date: ' + CAST(@LastDayOfMonth AS NVARCHAR(20))        
    PRINT ''   
    SET @dt = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @dt)    
END
```

This will work so long as `@dt` is the first of the month, otherwise you will have to create a new `@FirstDayOfMonth` variable and set this above the Setting of `@LastDayOfMonth', but the above should be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for that. However the last day of the month is not always going to be the actual last day of the month. For example sometimes the last day of the month will be the 25th and in that case 26th - 31st would fall in to Feb and the start of Jan would be 26th Dec. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Might be worth updating the question with the details on these rules. e.g. How is the SQL to know the required month length? How do you know which months have the last-day as the 25th?

Comment: It's in there as "DECLARE @monthEndDate INT = 30" This will be preset for the entire operation and will apply to all months. However the SQL needs to be able to accept any value here. It could be 31, 30 , 29, 28 etc